# Expected an Integer

Tags: python, image-processing, theano, video-tracking

I am getting error in last line of the code. Saying "Expected an Integer".
Actually this code took from VGGNET. I am using Python 3.6.9.

```
import theano.tensor as T
batch,in_channels,H,W = T.shape(x)
self.VGGout_resize = 16
xt = x[:,::-1,:,:]
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,0,:,:], xt[:,0,:,:] - 103.939)
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,1,:,:], xt[:,1,:,:] - 116.779)
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,2,:,:], xt[:,2,:,:] - 123.68)
xt = xt[:,:,0:self.VGGout_resize* 
(H/self.VGGout_resize),0:self.VGGout_resize*(W/self.VGGout_resize) ]
```

["Error Results Image 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC2U5.png)
 ["Error Results Image 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQFs0.png)

Comment: Post whole error message with full traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're slicing and output of `(H/self.VGGout_resize)` or `(W/self.VGGout_resize)` could be a non-integer. Try this:

```
self.VGGout_resize = 16
xt = x[:,::-1,:,:]
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,0,:,:], xt[:,0,:,:] - 103.939)
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,1,:,:], xt[:,1,:,:] - 116.779)
xt = T.set_subtensor(xt[:,2,:,:], xt[:,2,:,:] - 123.68)
xt = xt[:,:,0:self.VGGout_resize*int(H/self.VGGout_resize),0:self.VGGout_resize*int(W/self.VGGout_resize)]
```

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TensorVariable'  i got this error when i am doing type conversion

Comment: What are your H and W? Can you show me the code where they're declared?

Comment: `batch,in_channels,H,W = T.shape(x)`